# how to install mongo.so for PHP7 on OSX ElCapitan

Tags: macos, mongodb, php-7

I am running OSX 10.11.3
PHP 7.0.2 (cli) (built: Jan  8 2016 10:14:20) ( NTS )
after executing 
`sudo pecl install mongodb` 
I do have an error:

> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.16/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mongodb.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.16/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mongodb.so, 9): Symbol not found: _zval_used_for_init
>     Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.16/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mongodb.so
>     Expected in: flat namespace
>    in /usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.16/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mongodb.so in Unknown on line 0

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you could have a try to config php.ini with extension = mongodb.so, if not, maybe due to version match question.